# Issue with System.Xml.Linq on Mono

Tags: c#, .net, mono, linq-to-xml, raspbian

I am building a simple application targeting .NET 4.0. It's a POC which I am building using Visual Studio 2010 and running it on Mono in Raspbian.

I got past the Hello World stage and now I added a 3rd party [Matrix XMPP SDK](http://www.ag-software.net/matrix-xmpp-sdk/). The application is working completely fine in Windows.

So I copy the files over to Raspbian and run `mono SampleForm.exe`. It doesn't run and give an exception so I run it with the `--debug` flag and part of the debug log says something like below. ([Full log](http://pastebin.com/tJNkAChU))

```
Mono: The request to load the assembly System.Xml.Linq v3.5.0.0 was remapped to v4.0.0.0
Mono: Assembly Loader probing location: '/usr/lib/mono/gac/System.Xml.Linq/4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.Xml.Linq.dll'.
Mono: Assembly Loader probing location: '/mnt/win/System.Xml.Linq.dll'.
Mono: Assembly Loader probing location: '/usr/lib/System.Xml.Linq.dll'.
Mono: Assembly Loader probing location: '/usr/lib/mono/4.5/Facades/System.Xml.Linq.dll'.
Mono: Assembly Loader probing location: '/usr/lib/mono/gac/System.Xml.Linq/4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.Xml.Linq.exe'.
Mono: Assembly Loader probing location: '/mnt/win/System.Xml.Linq.exe'.
Mono: Assembly Loader probing location: '/usr/lib/System.Xml.Linq.exe'.
Mono: Assembly Loader probing location: '/usr/lib/mono/4.5/Facades/System.Xml.Linq.exe'.
Mono: The following assembly referenced from /mnt/win/Matrix.dll could not be loaded:
     Assembly:   System.Xml.Linq    (assemblyref_index=1)
     Version:    3.5.0.0
     Public Key: b77a5c561934e089
The assembly was not found in the Global Assembly Cache, a path listed in the MONO_PATH environment variable, or in the location of the executing assembly (/mnt/win/).

Mono: Failed to load assembly Matrix[0x15c30b0]

Mono: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Xml.Linq, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' or one of its dependencies.
Mono: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Xml.Linq, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' or one of its dependencies.
Mono: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Xml.Linq, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' or one of its dependencies.
Mono: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Xml.Linq, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' or one of its dependencies.
Mono: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Xml.Linq, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' or one of its dependencies.
System.TypeLoadException: Could not load type 'Matrix.Xmpp.Client.XmppClient' from assembly 'Matrix, Version=1.5.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=41a432ad608f2ff0'.
  at XMPPHandler.DotNetXMPPClient..ctor () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
```

Things I tried to solve it:

1. Compile for .NET 3.5. However, that caused more errors and the Win Form did not even appear.
2. I tried doing a binding redirect but that did not work.

   ```
   <runtime>  
     <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">  
         <dependentAssembly>
           <assemblyIdentity name="System.Xml.Linq" publicKeyToken="b77a5c561934e089" />
           <bindingRedirect oldVersion="3.5.0.0" newVersion="4.0.0.0"/>
         </dependentAssembly>
       </assemblyBinding>
   </runtime>
   ```
3. I tried putting the 3.5 version of System.Xml.Linq into my VS project but it kept automatically changing it back to 4.0
4. I tried looking for a way to install v.4.0.0 for System.Xml.Linq and found that `sudo apt-get install mono-data` should do it but I was told that the package was not found (even after apt-get update). I checked the `/usr/lib/mono/gac/System.Xml.Linq` directory and only the directory `3.5.0.0__b77a5c561934e089` was present.
5. I install libmono-system-xml-linq4.0-cil and then ran the application. Now I get a segmentation fault.

How can I install version 4.0.0.0 or is there anything else I can do to make it work?

Comment: what version of mono are you using?

Comment: I am using Mono JIT compiler version 3.2.8 (Debian 3.2.8+dfsg-4+rpi1)

Comment: ok, this could be a mono bug, because I don't see this assembly being listed here: https://github.com/mono/mono/blob/e3b9881e5707953bd37fb3ed0dbeab93e6603a5e/mono/metadata/assembly.c#L74 I recommend filing a bug in bugzilla.xamarin.com with a minimal testcase first, and then try to compile your own mono adding that assembly to assembly.c to try to fix it (if you achieve it, propose your change as a pull request)

Answer (score 0):

i am using mono 3.6 (= very new version compiled from source) on Debian and got System.Xml.Linq working. The only problem i encountered has been that System.Xml.Linq.dll was copied local.

Answer (score 0):

This kind of problems usually happen when your Mono does not have some dotnet library installed. You need to install donet system xml lib for your Mono (on Raspbian):

```
apt-get install libmono-system-xml-linq4.0-cil
```

I my case I needed to install manually some of this libraries. For Raspbian I installed the following libraries:

```
apt-get install libmono-system-xml-linq4.0-cil
apt-get install libmono-system-web-extensions4.0-cil
```

If you application under Mono does not run because some another library is not found you can see all available libraries for Mono [here](https://packages.debian.org/sid/cli-mono/).